# How to "wake-up" an Azure webjob from within a mobile service?

Tags: node.js, azure-mobile-services, azure-webjobs

Let's say I have an Azure webjob configured as **singleton**, and running "continuously" in a **free-site** context. According to the [Azure specifications](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/), after a certain period from the start the webjob is shut down, unless someone will keep it running:

> As of March 2014, websites in Free mode can time out after 20 minutes
>   if there are no requests to the scm (deployment) site and the
>   website's portal is not open in Azure. Requests to the actual site
>   will not reset this.

However, that's fine to me. My goal is "waking-up" the webjob instance upon the invocation of a mobile-service custom API, as the basic following example:

```
exports.post = function(request, response) {
    //ensure the webjob running, in case wake it up
    var rq = require('request');
    rq("http:// ??? (any site to invoke?) ", function(error, response, body) {
        //do nothing
    });

    //do specific stuffs related to the mobile service
    var rtn = { message : 'Hello World!' };
    rtn.req = request.body;
    response.send(statusCodes.OK, rtn);
};
```

All I need is the same behavior as the staircase timed-light: once someone presses the light button, the lights will turn one for a period of time. If someone presses another button while the lights are on, the same lights keep lighting on. Hoping to give the sense...

My problem is finding an easy way to "indirectly-invoke" the webjob, so that it will be restarted.

Comment: Note that the is no point in configuring a WebJob running on a free website as singleton as it will always run on a single instance.

Comment: I added the property `"is_singleton": true` in the webjob-publish-settings.json file of my VS WebJob project. You mean that is actually ignored in the free-site context?

Comment: It's not ignored just redundant

Comment: Yeah! That's the right term, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "wake up" the WebJob you need to make a request to the scm site which is: https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net

The call needs to be authenticated and you can do that with basic auth providing the website's deployment credentials, you can get it by downloading the **publish profile** from the website's dashboard in the Azure portal.

[image]

Comment: Still can't say that's working. I tried several URL forms (even on the 443 port), with basic auth. Despite the query against the URI is running fine (no errors and some data available as body), the job keep sticking to "stopped": the log confirm that there's no activity. If I explicitly start from within the portal, it starts normally, then shuts down after 20-30 mins. Also tried this, with no results: http://wp.sjkp.dk/azure-website-slow-on-first-request-part-ii/

Comment: To make sure you're making the right request, try making a request to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/jobs and see that you're getting your job back, maybe make another one 10 seconds later to make sure the job is running (status will be in the response).

Comment: Finally it works! Honestly, this is the first time I see such a URI : is there explained somewhere? Also, I realized that once you stop the webjob from within the Azure dashboard, it can't be restored unless you explicitly run it again. I'd change the button caption as "enabled/disabled": run/stop may lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

POST an empty request to:
https://{cotainername}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/jobs/continuous/{webjobname}/start

with the userName and userPWD values from the {website}\publishprofile{containername}.azurewebsites.net.publish.settings file,
in the first node with attribute publishMethod="MSDeploy"

I've just tested this myself - as I have a similar situation about free site jobs going to sleep.

Comment: Many thanks, but I solved it since a while. Here is how I done: https://highfieldtales.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/azure-veneziano-part-2/